# List variable does not exist in current context and I have a reference to System.Collections.Generic

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scoring
{
    //Scrapes labour from excel files.
    class LaborScrape
    {
        //folder with all the utilites
        string utilitiesDir = @"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\ScrapSafe\UTILITIES";

        //folder with the labour
        string labourDir = @"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\ScrapSafe\SCORING";

        //overhead list of names
        List<string> test = new List<string>();
        test

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error `The name 'test' does not exist in the current context.` with the variable `test` and the linter states that test does not exist in the current context. I'm under the impression that I have all the references needed above to be able to use the list class. I'm not very proficient in c#, however, and am at a loss as to why there's no reference to the variable I just declared.

I've tried other list types as well and still get the error message.
I've also tried to call .Add("test") and build it but the build fails.
Prefixing the variable with `public` and `private` doesn't help either.

Comment: Why do you have the word `test` underneath your declaration of the property `test`? Perhaps that is what is causing the  error....

Comment: What are you trying to do with `test`?  Are you trying to list/display all of its contents?  Considering you instantiated the list, but did not provide it with any data, it currently is a `List` of type `string` with nothing in it.

Comment: You'll need to put your code in a method, only member declarations (like fields, properties, methods, etc) can be added to a class directly, other code must be placed inside a method. (i.e. you can declare `List<string> test = new List<string>()` on your class, but can only use it within an instance method declared in that class)

Comment: I have it there because VS isn't recognizing the name and when I try to call a List method on it, it still gives me the same error message plus 
`The name 'test.Add' does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: @bassfader This was the problem. Thank you. I don't use c# very often and I totally biffed the object orientated rules with this. How do I close this question?

Comment: @NoleloN No problem, glad I could help :) I just created an answer based on my comment, which you could mark as answer for this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't add code directly inside a `class` declaration, you'll need a method for your code.

So for example you could add a constructor to the `LaborScrape` class, to add some initial data to your `test` list whenever you create a new `LaborScrape` instance:

```
class LaborScrape
{
    //folder with all the utilites
    string utilitiesDir = @"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\ScrapSafe\UTILITIES";

    //folder with the labour
    string labourDir = @"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\ScrapSafe\SCORING";

    //overhead list of names
    List<string> test = new List<string>();

    public LaborScrape() {
        test.Add("Some value");
        test.Add("Some other value");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could of course also add some other method declaration to your class that you call explicitly to do the "actual work" when required.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the answer with some examples.